# TensorBoard scalar summary differs from plotting the loss values with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorboard, tensor, scalar

I am trying to visualize top and bottom 10% of the loss, so I export the loss values to a csv file, for further processing.

In TensorBoard the scalar representation of my loss with 0 smoothing looks like this:

[image]

The plot made from the csv file, without any alteration to the values looks like this:

[image]

The code where I add the values to the summarywriter and csv file:

```
self.writer.add_scalar('Regression_loss/train:', loss_reg, global_step)
traincsv.write(str(global_step) + "," + str(loss_reg.data.item()) + "\n")
```

I compared the content of the `csv` to the `matplotlib` plot, and it matches, so why does the TensorBoard, show different values?

Comment: Before answering your question, I think you first need to use the same range as `tensorboard`. As you can see, in `matplotlib` the x-axis range is set to `25k` while it's `20k`  for tensorboard

Comment: Yes, the range differs, but without setting it to the same, we can see, that the periodicity that shows in the matplotlib plot is not present in the tensorboard plot.